# При уменьшении размеров экрана, после блока появлется пустота

Tags: html, css

вот сам блок

```css
.end_info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 8vw;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.end_info_item {
  margin-top: 2vw;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}

.end_info_item ul li {
  margin-top: 3vw;
  margin-left: 2vw;
}

.end_info_item ul li a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="end_info">
  <div class="mesto end_info_item">Наши адреса:
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЙ-ТО АДРЕС</a></li>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЙ-ТО АДРЕС</a></li>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЙ-ТО АДРЕС</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="time end_info_item">ЧАСЫ РАБОТЫ:
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЕ-ТО ВРЕМЯ КАКОЙ-ТО ДЕНЬ</a></li>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЕ-ТО ВРЕМЯ КАКОЙ-ТО ДЕНЬ</a></li>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЕ-ТО ВРЕМЯ КАКОЙ-ТО ДЕНЬ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cvyaz end_info_item">Связаться с нами:
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">ЧТО-ТО</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ЧТО-ТО</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ЧТО-ТО</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Возможно ли это из-за того, что я везде использовал vw?

Comment: Отредактируйте свое сообщение, приложив весь код на сайте ruSO, никто не будет бегать смотреть чего же у вас такое

Comment: я немножно не понял, что за ruSO, я могу его сюда весь выложить, но получится довольно много

Comment: Почитайте - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: редактировал, вроде нашел проблемное место

Answer (score 0):

Вроде ничего не появляется, height: 399px; только поменял.

```css
.end_info{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-around;
margin-top: 8vw;
background-color: black;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.end_info_item{
margin-top: 2vw;
color: white;
font-size: 1.5vw;
}
.end_info_item ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.end_info_item ul li{
    margin-top: 3vw;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}


.end_info_item ul li a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="end_info">
  <div class="mesto end_info_item">Наши адреса:
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЙ-ТО АДРЕС</a></li>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЙ-ТО АДРЕС</a></li>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЙ-ТО АДРЕС</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="time end_info_item">ЧАСЫ РАБОТЫ:
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЕ-ТО ВРЕМЯ КАКОЙ-ТО ДЕНЬ</a></li>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЕ-ТО ВРЕМЯ КАКОЙ-ТО ДЕНЬ</a></li>
      <li><a href="">КАКОЕ-ТО ВРЕМЯ КАКОЙ-ТО ДЕНЬ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="cvyaz end_info_item">Связаться с нами:
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">ЧТО-ТО</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ЧТО-ТО</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ЧТО-ТО</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```